# Let $u=(u_1,\cdots,u_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then is $\min(u)$ a correct notation?

Tags: notation

Let $u=(u_1,\cdots,u_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then is $\min(u)$ a correct notation for the quantity $\min(u_1,\cdots u_n)$? Is it normal to use such notation?
For example if i write for a function $C^{+}$

$C^{+}(u)=\min(u) \forall u \in [0,1]^n$

is this the same as saying

$$C^{+}(u)=\min(u_1,u_2, \cdots,u_n)$$

Comment: I never encountered that notation.

Comment: @drhab I updated the question with a little more context

Comment: I'm almost positive it is not a standard notation and thus either you drop it or else you define it clearly for a paper, an exam or whatever.

Comment: @DonAntonio  Alright thank you very much . I will fix it

Comment: The mathematician Peter Neumann used to say that it was the mathematician's prerogative to define, meaning that he/she could, in principle, define any notation to mean anything at all. But, he claimed this prerogative should be used only when it was really necessary so as not to confuse the reader.